# TCP packet flow in Docker container compared to Host system

Tags: docker, networking, tcp

I'm trying to understand the flow of TCP packets for a single HTTP request from within a Docker container and need help understanding the differences in how the packets get handled by the container and host.

### Setup

#### Host

- OS: OSX 10.15.7
- Local IP: 192.168.178.46

#### Docker container:

- OS: Debian 10.8
- Local IP: 172.17.0.2
- Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

#### Remote Server

- Public IP: 3.1.228.121
- Round trip time from local to remote: ~300ms

### Test

I started `tcpdump` on both the host and Docker container and then triggered an HTTP request from within the container. Pasted below are the relevant TCP packets for one such request (the timing information is misaligned due to timezone differences and clock drift). I've manually prefixed numbers to the packets to ease correlation:

#### Container

```
C1: 07:33:36.103984 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 172.17.0.2.54104: Flags [P.], seq 5326:5918, ack 1552, win 65535, length 592
C2: 07:33:36.104026 IP 172.17.0.2.54104 > 3.1.228.121.443: Flags [.], ack 5918, win 501, length 0
C3: 07:33:36.131415 IP 172.17.0.2.54104 > 3.1.228.121.443: Flags [P.], seq 1552:1795, ack 5918, win 501, length 243
C4: 07:33:36.131750 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 172.17.0.2.54104: Flags [.], ack 1795, win 65535, length 0
C5: 07:33:36.133539 IP 172.17.0.2.54104 > 3.1.228.121.443: Flags [P.], seq 1795:2460, ack 5918, win 501, length 665
C6: 07:33:36.133992 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 172.17.0.2.54104: Flags [.], ack 2460, win 65535, length 0
C7: 07:33:36.464602 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 172.17.0.2.54104: Flags [P.], seq 5918:6539, ack 2460, win 65535, length 621
```

#### Host

```
H1a: 08:33:36.081470 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 192.168.178.46.61686: Flags [P.], seq 5326:5869, ack 1552, win 119, options [nop,nop,TS val 821705852 ecr 615669315], length 543
H1b: 08:33:36.081471 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 192.168.178.46.61686: Flags [P.], seq 5869:5918, ack 1552, win 119, options [nop,nop,TS val 821705852 ecr 615669315], length 49
H2a: 08:33:36.081524 IP 192.168.178.46.61686 > 3.1.228.121.443: Flags [.], ack 5869, win 2039, options [nop,nop,TS val 615669695 ecr 821705852], length 0
H2b: 08:33:36.081533 IP 192.168.178.46.61686 > 3.1.228.121.443: Flags [.], ack 5918, win 2038, options [nop,nop,TS val 615669695 ecr 821705852], length 0
H3:  08:33:36.109309 IP 192.168.178.46.61686 > 3.1.228.121.443: Flags [P.], seq 1552:1795, ack 5918, win 2048, options [nop,nop,TS val 615669722 ecr 821705852], length 243
H5:  08:33:36.111446 IP 192.168.178.46.61686 > 3.1.228.121.443: Flags [P.], seq 1795:2460, ack 5918, win 2048, options [nop,nop,TS val 615669724 ecr 821705852], length 665
H6:  08:33:36.431651 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 192.168.178.46.61686: Flags [.], ack 2460, win 129, options [nop,nop,TS val 821706249 ecr 615669722], length 0
H7a: 08:33:36.441653 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 192.168.178.46.61686: Flags [P.], seq 5918:6461, ack 2460, win 129, options [nop,nop,TS val 821706253 ecr 615669722], length 543
H7b: 08:33:36.441658 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 192.168.178.46.61686: Flags [P.], seq 6461:6505, ack 2460, win 129, options [nop,nop,TS val 821706253 ecr 615669722], length 44
H7c: 08:33:36.441658 IP 3.1.228.121.443 > 192.168.178.46.61686: Flags [P.], seq 6505:6539, ack 2460, win 129, options [nop,nop,TS val 821706253 ecr 615669722], length 34
```

The host system is aggregating multiple packets before forwarding them to Docker and I've tried to show this in the numbering above.

### Questions

<s>1. The remote server's window buffer size as published in packet `H1b` is `119`. How is the host system able to publish two successive packets of size `243` and `665` that exceed this size?</s>

A: The `window scale` was set to 8 in the `SYN+ACK` packet so the calculated window size is `119*2^8 = 30464`

2. The container receives an `Ack` packet `C4` (supposedly from the remote server) in less than a millisecond which is physically not possible. This packet also does not have a correlating packet on the Host and it seems like something Docker injected. Is this understanding correct and is this allowed under TCP?

Answer (score 0):

In case of macOS, docker is running in a small VM on the host, so the traffic flow logic differs from a a docker running on a Linux host.

Since there is a VM involved, the VM will have a virtual network interface attached to the host. On a very high level, you can say that you have a kind of a router inside your host that will route the traffic from external network adapter to the docker engine via the VM network interface so the high level of packet flow will be:

```
Linux:
[Client] -> [Host nic] -> [NW bridge (ex. docker0)] -> [Container]
maxOS:
[Client] -> [Host nic] -> [VM nic] -> [NW bridge (ex. docker0)] -> [Container]
```

To mask the existence of this networks, the adapters (on the host and on the VM) will apply NAT on the packets. So when you add the nat, you might think of it as a proxy.

Note that this is oversimplification and will differ from the type of network drivers you have for the docker network, however it will always be true that you will pass trough the VM's nic in case of macOS.

Now to answer the questions in a simple way, you are observing two separate flows, and you are missing the flow in the middle and the translations that are happening.

Check more here https://argus-sec.com/docker-networking-behind-the-scenes/ about the normal flow, and here https://collabnix.com/how-docker-for-mac-works-under-the-hood/

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the links. 
I'll check them out to understand this better.

However, the presence of additional bridges/NICs on the path to the Docker container should not affect the  TCP packet observations on the host system, right?  As outlined in Question 1, I would have thought that since the `win` attribute in packet `H1b` is set by the remote server, the host system must respect it irrespective of what is happening internally.

The impact of the NICs on question 2 is something to dig into.

Comment: I would also say that the presence of the VM nic should not affect since this is an L2 traffic, however to say this for sure we will need further research. For the `win` issue, you might be see the assembled packets and not the fragments that flow in the network [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550959/how-to-capture-tcp-ip-fragmentation-in-tcpdump)